# how to change type: global variable use before define

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

In my case, I need to create a reference to a global variable in the module and then define the global variable after the reference.

When I create the instruction which will use the global varaible, I don't know the type of the variable. Even I actually only need the address of the symbol, I still need to create a llvm::GlobalVariable object by specifying a type.

This caused a problem, when I define the global variable later, I know the type but unfortunately I am not able to replace the GlobalVariable object I created before.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
llvm::Value *val = new llvm::GlobalVariable(module, llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(), false
          , llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0, "myvar");

//.... create instructions
builder.CreatePtrToInt(val, llvm::Type::getInt32Ty());

//Here I need to define and intialize the global variable. 
//Now I know the exact type of   the variable. It's different as int32 
//for example it's int16.

llvm::Value *real_val = new llvm::GlobalVariable(module, llvm::Type::getInt16Ty()
          , false,llvm::GlobalValue::ExternalLinkage, 0, "myvar");
```

Obviously, I can't create another variable with same name. But how can I convert the first GlobalVariable object to the actual type and give an initializer to it?

Is there any other way to get a symbol address without creating an GlobalVariable object?

Comment: Why can't you create instruction after GlovalVariable was defined with right type? In LLVM you cannot use variable before it was defined.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my situation, I have to do this:(